# WordPress | New Theme Style Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

everyone.

I made a new theme, and I don't know why the style is not working - the CSS and JS don't work at all

This is my functions.php file:

```
<?php



// Loading CSS & JS //

    function Resources(){

        // CSS //
            wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap_css', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');
            wp_enqueue_style('theme_css', get_stylesheet_uri());
        // CSS//

        //JavaScript //

            wp_enqueue_script('jquery', '//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js');
            wp_enqueue_script('jquery_migrate', '//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js');
            wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap_js', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js');

        //JavaScript//


    }

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'Resources');

// Loading CSS & JS //

    //Require WordPress Bootstrap Navwalker
    require_once('custom_things/wp-bootstrap-navwalker/wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php');

//Loading Resources//



// Menus //

    add_theme_support('menus');

    register_nav_menus( array(
       'main' => __('Main Menu'),
    ) );

// Menus //



?>
```

Comment: Are you running the website on localhost or on the web?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove this line from your code

```
wp_enqueue_style('theme_css', get_stylesheet_uri());
```

and your code start working.

Comment: Thanks! It helped.